# Search a pattern and fold the matching lines in gvim

Tags: search, vim, code-folding

---

Hi ,

I want to fold set of lines after search as follows,

> The mouse can also be used to open and close folds by following steps:
>
> - Click on a '+' to open the closed fold at this row.
> - Click on any other non-blank character to close the open fold at this row

I want to search **click** and collapse all matching lines.

> The mouse can also be used to open and close folds by followingsteps:
>
> +--

There is a method to collapse the patterns which are not matching in vim , after searching a pattern we can collapse non matching patterns by "\z" key .

`nnoremap \z :setlocal foldexpr=(getline(v:lnum)=~@/)?0:(getline(v:lnum-1)=~@/)\\|\\|(getline(v:lnum+1)=~@/)?1:2 foldmethod=expr foldlevel=0 foldcolumn=2<CR>` 
Is there any option to do the opposite? Just find a pattern and collapse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to this question from reddit user on reddit vim forum.

https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/91qz90/search_a_pattern_and_fold_the_matching_lines_in/

```
function! FoldSearchPattern() abort
    if !exists('w:foldpatterns')
        let w:foldpatterns=[]
        setlocal foldmethod=expr foldlevel=0 foldcolumn=2
    endif
    if index(w:foldpatterns, @/) == -1
        call add(w:foldpatterns, @/)
        setlocal foldexpr=SetFolds(v:lnum)
    endif
endfunction

function! SetFolds(lnum) abort
    for pattern in w:foldpatterns
        if getline(a:lnum) =~ pattern
            if getline(a:lnum + 1) !~ pattern
                return 's1'
            else
                return 1
            endif
        endif
    endfor
endfunction

nnoremap \z :call FoldSearchPattern()<CR>
```

Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using below configuration with `neovim` I think should work with regular `vim` as well:

```
nnoremap \Z :setlocal foldexpr=(getline(v:lnum)=~@/)?0:1 foldmethod=expr foldlevel=0 foldcolumn=2 foldminlines=0<CR><CR>
nnoremap \z :setlocal foldexpr=(getline(v:lnum)=~@/)?1:0 foldmethod=expr foldlevel=0 foldcolumn=2 foldminlines=0<CR><CR>
```

`\z`: Fold matching expression from last search
`\Z`: Fold anything that's `NOT` matching from last search

It's quite useful when I want to see all comments or no comments at all,
First do `\` and search for `^#` (If that's your language's comment start symbol) hit return, then do the folding as above.

Edit: You might want to add below to reset the folding back to manual if you want:
`nnoremap \F :setlocal foldmethod=manual<CR><CR>`

Comment: sdkks This one is simple. When i set the foldmethod=manual command in vimrc after your 2 commands, i am unable to unfold it. Do i need to set it manually again in vim window everytime, if in case i want to unfold?.
The folding is restricted to one search,can we expand it to more than one search pattern.

Comment: @EashwarGadanchi you can unfold everything with `zE` after setting method to manual with `\F` . If I understand you right, you want to accumulate folds with different search every time, I'm afraid with this simple method it's not possible as command is seeking and folding everything based on particular expression. I'd look for a plugin for that advanced use case. I haven't tried any yet.